# SSH connection continuously dropping

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I have configured my SSH connection as follows: `~/.ssh/config` on client side

```
ServerAliveInterval 1
ServerAliveCountMax 1200
```

and in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on server side:

```
ClientAliveInterval 5                                                                                                          
ClientAliveCountMax 1200
```

Still, when logging into a remote server, and while I would consider my connection quite stable, I see my SSH connection continuously being dropped after about 15 to 60 seconds. `ssh <server> -vvv` always ends with

```
...
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 82
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 100
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection reset by <IP> port <PORT>
```

While on server side:

```
...
debug3: receive packet: type 80                                                                                                
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1                                                  
debug3: send packet: type 82                                                                                                   
debug3: receive packet: type 80                                                                                                
debug1: server_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1                                                  
debug3: send packet: type 82                                                                                                   
debug2: channel 0: request keepalive@openssh.com confirm 1                                                                     
debug3: send packet: type 98                                                                                                   
debug2: channel 0: request keepalive@openssh.com confirm 1                                                                     
debug3: send packet: type 98                                                                                                   
debug2: channel 0: request keepalive@openssh.com confirm 1                                                                     
debug3: send packet: type 98                                                                                                   
debug2: channel 0: request keepalive@openssh.com confirm 1                                                                     
debug3: send packet: type 98
...
```

The server indeed keeps on retrying. Also in parallel I can download something or even open a parallel SSH connection to the same server.

But even if there was a short outage, why does the SSH client not keep on retrying but quit prematurely? How can I configure SSH to (really) keep on retrying?

Comment: What I noticed is that, while if I do not interfere the disconnect does always happen, if I start another ssh session right while the repeated type 80 messages appear, the connection often recovers:

Comment: debug3: send packet: type 80
    debug3: send packet: type 80
    debug3: send packet: type 80
    debug3: receive packet: type 98
    debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
    debug3: send packet: type 100
    debug3: receive packet: type 82
    debug3: receive packet: type 82
    debug3: receive packet: type 82
    debug3: receive packet: type 82
    debug3: receive packet: type 82
    debug3: send packet: type 80
    debug3: receive packet: type 82
    debug3: send packet: type 80
    debug3: receive packet: type 82

Comment: It seems like you're hitting TCP timeouts, and the keepalives are probably actively harmful to your goal...

Comment: @grawity: How can I check for this? I tried `ping` but it always comes back within 23ms. I there a setting I can change to enlarge TCP timeouts?

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly a solution to my problem but at least I am able to work around the issue by running a process in another shell which in parallel logs into the remote server every second, like

```
 while true ; do ssh <server> "date; sleep 1s"; done
```

I don't know why, but it effectively prevents the issues posed in my initial question above.

Comment: I tried this, but this not worked.